# Object has no method

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the following JS class, http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/docs/examples.html.

I've been stuck on this searching for a good amount of time now, trying to debug this and I have no idea what is going on.  The guys examples work, I don't understand why I am getting this error, which is Object #InfoBox has no method 'open'.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.7620078,-79.5044951);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var labelText = "City Hall";
    var myOptions2 = {
        content: labelText,
        boxStyle: {
            border: "1px solid black",
            textAlign: "center",
            fontSize: "8pt",
            width: "50px"
        },
        disableAutoPan: true,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-25, 0),
        position: latlng,
        closeBoxURL: "",
        isHidden: false,
        pane: "mapPane",
        enableEventPropagation: true
    };

    var ibLabel = new InfoBox(myOptions2);
    ibLabel.open(map);      
});
</script>
```

**Update:**
I've found the solution on the interwebs.  I was loading the InfoBox javascript file before the google maps api.

Loading the google maps api first has solved all problems.

Comment: That is pretty strange. Is it possible that some other library you are including defines a conflicting constructor for type 'InfoBox'?

Comment: I've updated the original post with what the problem was.  I'm happy it's finally solved.

Comment: @Marcin You should answer you own question below so it's clear what the solution is.